# Не работает focus через onClick ( useRef )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
LogoWrapper это div.

```js
export const LogoWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-left: 2rem;
  &:focus {
    animation: ${ logoAnimation } 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  }
`
В devtools ставлю фокус на этот div -- работает.

в logoRef -- мой div ( вывела в логе )
```

Код

================================================================================

```js
import React, { useContext, FC, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import { TextContext } from '@context'
import { GraphLogo } from '@icons'
import { 
  HeaderContainer,
  LogoWrapper,
  ContentWrapper,
  LogoText
} from '@layoutComponents/Header/styles'



const Header= (props) => {
  const {txt} = useContext(TextContext)
  const history = useHistory()
  const logoRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(false)
  
  
  // const handleClick = () => {
  //   history.push('/home')
  //   console.log(logoRef.current)
  //   // @ts-ignore
  //   logoRef.current.focus()
  //   const interval = setInterval(() => {
  //      return   logoRef.current!.focus()
  //   }, 5000);
  //   return () => {
  //     clearInterval(interval);
  //   };
  // }
  //
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    setAnimation(!animation)
  }
  
  
  return (
    <HeaderContainer>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <LogoText onClick={handleClick}>{txt.header.mainTitle}</LogoText>
        <LogoWrapper animation={animation}>
          <GraphLogo />
        </LogoWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper> 
    </HeaderContainer>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: Через useState --работает. Почему не работает через ref ? )

Comment: @nörbörnën знаете ?

Comment: а собственно где элемент на кoтором прикреплен ref?

Comment: @Armen Он на фото, LogoWrapper

Comment: у дива есть tabIndex?

Comment: лутше добавить полный код чем рисунок и пол кода

Comment: @Armen нет, нету

Comment: @Armen Так есть образец кода ниже, он закоментирован

Comment: :) образец кода не показывает на ком висит ref образец кода не показывает как он заработал с useState ну да лан добавь tabIndex к div-у все заработает я вообше до этого не знал что элементы вроде div имеют фокусировку)

Comment: @Armen Спасибо, а почему так ? ( tabIndex  )

Comment: не углубился но по логике у таких элементов как input есть по дефоулту табихндех вот они и получают фокус если интересуют детали лутше погуглить, не за что